# ReactJS - Warning: Unknown prop `onTouchTap` on <label> tag. Remove this prop from the element

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, redux-form

I took the example from http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/material-ui/ and ran it on my localhost. I received the error:

Warning: Unknown prop `onTouchTap` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element

The error comes from material-ui plugin. Anyone already solved it yet ?

Comment: check this one, try the suggested solutions: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4670

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines on your app

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

before `ReactDOM.render();`